# INSERT with PDO $_POST not working

Tags: php, post, pdo, insert

**SOLVED - ANSWER ADDED AT THE BOTTOM OF THE POST**

Please can someone help me out as I can´t understand what the heck I am doing wrong.
I have a html form with 2 fields "title" and "message". I´m trying to get this to go into the database with PDO and $_POST but I am just getting this error:

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null' in**

I´m doing everything by the book but it´s not working and I going to throw my computer out the window soon. So please anyone have any idea what is wrong? Why is title turning "NULL"?

The database is a 4 column table (id, title, message and timestamp). The id field is primary and auto intent

ANY help is really appreciated!!! And I´m a beginner...

Here is post.php file:

```
<?php 

require 'connect.inc.php';

$db = new DB('blogdata');

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO blogposts (title, message, time) VALUES (:title, :message, :time)");

$stmt->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']);
$stmt->bindParam(':message', $_POST['message']);
$stmt->bindParam(':time', $time);

$title = $_POST['title'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$stmt->execute();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Create blog post</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>

<!--- Add blog post ---> 

<div class="add_form">
    <form id="add_post" method="post" action="post.php" enctype="text/plain">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Create post</legend>
            <label for="post_title">Title:
                <input id="title" type="text" name="title" value="<?php if (isset($title)) { echo htmlentities ($title); } ?>" >
            </label>
            <label for="message">Message:
                <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="20" cols="30" maxlength="50" value="<?php if (isset($message)) { echo htmlentities ($message); } ?>" ></textarea>
            </label>                                        
        </fieldset>
        <input id="send" type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

And here is the connect.inc.php file:

```
<?php

class DB extends PDO
{
    public function __construct($dbname = "blogdata")
    {
        $opt = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8";
        parent::__construct($dsn, "root", "", $opt);
    }
}

?>
```

**ANSWER:**

This issue was finally solved. The problem is you need to check if $_POST is empty or not. And right after the `if (!empty($_POST)) {` set the `require 'connect.inc.php';`. Also to minimize code do like Dave Just said, change :

```
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']);
$stmt->bindParam(':message', $_POST['message']);
```

To:

```
$stmt->execute(array(':title' => $_POST['title'], ':message' => $_POST['message']));
```

Here is the working code in post.php:

```
<?php 

if (!empty($_POST)) {

  require 'connect.inc.php';

  $db = new DB('blogdata');

  $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO blogposts (title, message) VALUES (:title, :message)");
  $stmt->execute(array(':title' => $_POST['title'], ':message' => $_POST['message']));

  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  // Redirect to index.php
  header ('Location: index.php');
  exit;
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Create blog post</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>

<!--- Add blog post ---> 

<div class="add_form">
    <form id="add_post" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Create post</legend>
            <label for="post_title">Title:
                <input id="title" type="text" name="title" value="<?php if (isset($title)) { echo htmlentities ($title); } ?>" >
            </label>
            <label for="message">Message:
                <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="20" cols="30" maxlength="50" value="<?php if (isset($message)) { echo htmlentities ($message); } ?>" ></textarea>
            </label>                                        
        </fieldset>
        <input id="send" type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what does var_dump($_POST['title']) give you ?

Comment: It's apparently bad idea to post the same question twice. **Especially** if this question is already offtopic

Comment: Not completely same question!;) @YourCommonSense

Comment: Yes. and this one, "Tell me why my code doesn't work" is a complete offtopic

Comment: Why would you want to `bindParam()` if you can simply, `$stmt->execute(array(':title' => $_POST['title'], ':time' => $_POST['time']));`?

Comment: Since your php-script in the same file, there's no need to declare `action="post.php"` in your `<form>` tag. You can simply omit that.

Comment: @DaveJust The problem is finally solved:) Good point with exchanging bindParam() and remove action="post.php"! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't thrown the computer out the window already, you should've checked whether `$_POST` vars were set or not before passing them to a PDO execute statement.

```
<?php 
    require 'connect.inc.php';
    if( isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['message']) ) {
        $db = new DB('blogdata');
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO blogposts (title, message, time) VALUES (:title, :message, :time)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':message', $_POST['message']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':time', $time);
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $stmt->execute();
    }
?>
```

#### PS

I have no idea what `$time` would do there.

Comment: Thank you! I just solved it with some help and your answer is the same! :) However I just removed $time as well:) Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why would include connection even when `$_POST` is empty?! Shouldn't it be  `require 'connect.inc.php';` right after `if (..) {  <-Here on the next line?`

Comment: @DaveJust You´re right, I just added the working code in the question and put the connection after if (..) . Thank you!

Comment: @DaveJust I left that outside in case there were any further connections later in the script.